# ubuntu 15.04 64bit in desktop can't change time zone

Tags: timezone

I install ubuntu 15.04 64bit through vmware player,everything is OK. But i through "Time & Date Settings..." choose a time zone "Shanghai" that doesn't have effect, the clock still display a time of "Los Angeles". I also change time zone in terminal through "tzselect" now the terminal time is right, but the desktop clock is still display the "Los Angeles" time. Please help! I'm Chinese and my english is bad, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm understand problem for you. You can edit file /etc/timezone

```
[root@tannetto ~]# cp -p /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime 
cp: overwrite `/etc/localtime'? y
[root@tannetto ~]# vi /etc/timezone
# change to your own zone
Asia/Tokyo
```

This is example change timezone for you, you use with time zone "Shanghai".

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer solved my problem. I change the timezone to Asia/Shanghai in /etc/timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on one of my computer that doesn't display the french time correctly. I solved it by checking "Manually" in the Time and Date Settings, accessible by clicking on the clock in the panel. You can then manually choose the time you want.

If anybody has a cleaner way to solve the problem I'll be happy to learn it.

Comment: You don't understand my question. I have used your method, clicking on the clock in the panel and choose the time zone I want,but that doesn't become effective. I choose "Shanghai" time zone, but it still display "Los Angeles"'s time.

Comment: I'm not talking about choosing a timezone but to manually configure the time by entering the numbers. It's a little bit dirty but can be used as a temporary solution.

Comment: I have try, but it also don't become effective. It still display the time of "Los Angeles".

Comment: In the "Clock" tab in Time and Date Settings do you have the "Time in autodetected location" enabled ? If not I have no idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: No.  "Time in auto-detected location" is disabled. Thank you very much!